# How do you add a bootstrap contact form into the footer of a Wordpress site?

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

Ok, so this current setup works, but it needs to re-direct the user to a thank you page.

I'd much rather that the user could stay on the same page, and a little thank you message pops up instead.

The HTML is contained within the footer.php for a child-theme I created for my site.

See the live version here, form is contained in the footer:
[edit]nvm problem solved[/edit]

Note: the footer is hard coded so I am assuming their is no way to add a contact form plugin into it. Is that correct?

```
<h3>LEAVE US A MESSAGE</h3>
<form name="contactform" method="post" action="http://example.com/wp-content/themes/fullby-child/mail/mailer.php" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputName" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Name</label>
        <div class="col-lg-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" name="inputName" placeholder="Your Name">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputEmail1" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Email</label>
        <div class="col-lg-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" name="inputEmail" placeholder="Your Email">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputSubject" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Subject</label>
        <div class="col-lg-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputSubject" name="inputSubject" placeholder="Subject Message">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputPassword1" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Message</label>
        <div class="col-lg-10">
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" id="inputMessage" name="inputMessage" placeholder="Your message..."></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
                Send Message
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>



<?php
/* Set e-mail recipient */
$myemail = "jack@example.com";

/* Check all form inputs using check_input function */
$name = check_input($_POST['inputName'], "Your Name");
$email = check_input($_POST['inputEmail'], "Your E-mail Address");
$subject = check_input($_POST['inputSubject'], "Message Subject");
$message = check_input($_POST['inputMessage'], "Your Message");

/* If e-mail is not valid show error message */
if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $email))
{
show_error("Invalid e-mail address");
}
/* Let's prepare the message for the e-mail */

$subject = "Someone has sent you a message";

$message = "

Someone has sent you a message using your contac form:

Name: $name
Email: $email
Subject: $subject

Message:
$message

";

/* Send the message using mail() function */
mail($myemail, $subject, $message);

/* Redirect visitor to the thank you page */
header('Location: http://example.com');
exit();

/* Functions we used */
function check_input($data, $problem='')
{
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
if ($problem && strlen($data) == 0)
{
show_error($problem);
}
return $data;
}

function show_error($myError)
{
?>
<html>
<body>

<p>Please correct the following error:</p>
<strong><?php echo $myError; ?></strong>
<p>Hit the back button and try again</p>

</body>
</html>
<?php
exit();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well after some persistence, I've came up with a solution.

I've used some different .php code and placed it at the top of the footer.php template.

This means that after submitting a form, the user stays on the same page.

```
<?php
    /* Set e-mail recipient */
    $emailTo = "jack@example.com";

    if(isset($_POST['submitted'])) {
    if(trim($_POST['contactName']) === '') {
    $nameError = 'Please enter your name.';
    $hasError = true;
    } else {
    $name = trim($_POST['contactName']);
    }

    if(trim($_POST['email']) === '')  {
    $emailError = 'Please enter your email address.';
    $hasError = true; } else if (!preg_match("/^[[:alnum:]][a-z0-9_.-]*@[a-z0-9.-]+.[a-z]{2,4}$/i", trim($_POST['email']))) {
    $emailError = 'You entered an invalid email address.';
    $hasError = true;
    } else {
    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
    }

    if(trim($_POST['subject']) === '') {
    $subjectError = 'Please enter a subject.';
    $hasError = true;
    } else {
    $subject = trim($_POST['subject']);
    }

    if(trim($_POST['comments']) === '') {
    $commentError = 'Please enter a message.';
    $hasError = true;
    } else {                                

    if(function_exists('stripslashes')) {
    $comments = stripslashes(trim($_POST['comments']));
    } else {
    $comments = trim($_POST['comments']);
    }
    }

    if(!isset($hasError)) {

    $subject = '[PHP Snippets] From '.$name;
    $body = "Name: $name nnEmail: $email nnComments: $comments";
    $headers = 'From: '.$name.' <'.$emailTo.'>' . "rn" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email;

    wp_mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);
    $emailSent = true;
    }

} ?>
```

Then I use php around the form to display a thank you message when the form has been sent successfully.

The only issue was that after submitting the form, the user reloads the page but is at the top, instead of at the point where the form is located.

The workaround was to have

I had to make sure the footer was nested inside a  tag.

```
        <div class="col-md-4">

            <h3>LEAVE US A MESSAGE</h3>
            <div id="container">
                <div id="content">
                    <div class="align-center">

                        <div class="entry-content">
                            <?php if(isset($emailSent) && $emailSent == true) { ?>

                                <div class="thanks">    
                                    <p>Thanks, your message was sent successfully.</p>
                                </div>

                            <?php } else { ?>
                                <?php the_content(); ?>
                                <?php if(isset($hasError) || isset($captchaError)) { ?>
                                    <p class="error">Sorry, an error occured.</p>
                                <?php } ?>

                                <form action="#footer" id="contactForm" method="post" class="general-form">
                                    <div class="contactform">
                                        <input type="text" name="contactName" class="form-control" id="contactName" placeholder="Your Name.." value="<?php if(isset($_POST['contactName'])) echo $_POST['contactName'];?>" class="required requiredField" />
                                        <?php if($nameError != '') { ?>
                                            <span class="error"><?=$nameError;?></span>
                                        <?php } ?>

                                        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email.." value="<?php if(isset($_POST['email']))  echo $_POST['email'];?>" class="required requiredField email" />
                                        <?php if($emailError != '') { ?>
                                            <span class="error"><?=$emailError;?></span>
                                        <?php } ?>

                                        <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Subject.." value="<?php if(isset($_POST['subject']))  echo $_POST['subject'];?>" class="required requiredField subject" />
                                        <?php if($subjectError != '') { ?>
                                            <span class="error"><?=$subjectError;?></span>
                                        <?php } ?>

                                        <textarea name="comments" id="commentsText" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Message" rows="4" cols="100" class="required requiredField"><?php if(isset($_POST['comments'])) { if(function_exists('stripslashes')) { echo stripslashes($_POST['comments']); } else { echo $_POST['comments']; } } ?></textarea>
                                        <?php if($commentError != '') { ?>
                                            <span class="error"><?=$commentError;?></span>
                                        <?php } ?>

                                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary no-border" value="Send Message"></input></p>
                                    </div>

                                    <input type="hidden" name="submitted" id="submitted" value="true" />
                                </form>
                            <?php } ?>

                        </div><!-- .entry-content -->
                    </div><!-- .post -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Happy days! :)